# Filesystem for few large files

Tags: filesystems, truecrypt, xfs

I am looking for a filesystem suited for a few (no more than 5 or so) large-ish files (ranging from 10GB-100GB).  The files are already compressed (sparse support not needed).

The FS will be used to format a truecrypt container.  The filesystem will occupy the entire container and the container will be sized to its contents.

I have been considering XFS for its large file handling but it does seem to provide more features than I need.  Are there any really lightweight solutions or is XFS the way to go?

Comment: Why not EXT4? It has the same extents structure for files as XFS.

Answer (score 0):

You need a large block size to minimize seek times and improve throughoutput, in any case it is not htat clear that you will get a noticeable improvement. Read this: https://serverfault.com/questions/496007/choosing-file-system-block-size